# Detect Child id and call a slide toggle on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, slidetoggle

Basically I have a series of projects displayed on the page.

Each project consists of a container div, an image div inside, then a button inside that div. With another div there which is set to 'Display:none'. When the user clicks the 'button inside' the div set to 'display:none' slideToggles on each click...

I will have many of these on a page and am currently having to add new lines of code for the new 'id' of the button and the sliding div... Is there a way to detect the sliding div which is a child to the image div?

The current code I am using is:

```
$(function(){
    $("#lifestyledropdown").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#lifestyleimages").slideToggle();
    });

    $("#camarguedropdown").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#camargueimages").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Each follow the same pattern:

Project 1:
div id = 'name-A'dropdown   (id of the button to activate the slide toggle)
div id = 'name-A'images     (id of the div that slides down)

Project 2:
div id = 'name-B'dropdown   (id of the button to activate the slide toggle)
div id = 'name-B'images     (id of the div that slides down)

Each project will have the same layout just different content so I am assuming I can use a code to detect the 'name section'?

HTML for the projects:

```
<div class="projectcontent">
<div class="projectimg"><img src="images/imagemain.jpg" alt="project" />

<div id="gallerybutton">
<a href="#" id="lifestyledropdown"><img src="images/gallerycollapsewhite.png" alt="project" class="gallerycollapse"/>
<img src="images/gallerycollapseblack.png" alt="project" class="gallerycollapseB"/></a>
</div>

<div class="projecttext" style="color:#FFF;text-align:left;">
<img src="images/breakshortwhite.jpg" />

<p2>PROJECT NAME<br />
ESTOTAS AUT ALICIENI QUIBUS EXPEROR ESTIAT ESTO VOLORPORRUM EARIORIT EUM EUM ATE CUS MO ET ATEM. TAE RE VELENDI GNIATUR, UTATE ET PORUM HARIBER AERORATISI BLACCUP TATIBEA TIOREPE LLIQUAE PELENIH ILIBEA SAPITAM EUM MEUN.<p2>
</div>

<div class="expandablebox" id="lifestyleimages" style="display:none;">
<div class="projectimg"><img src="images/image-slider.jpg" alt="project" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Added to the bottom... still isn't working with code below...
have tried to change the id so it is not in the href but instead in the <div id="gallery button"> instead but doesn't make any difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "ends with" `$=` selector to get all `dropdown` ids and then use `next()` to `slideToggle()` the subsequent div:

```
$('div[id$="dropdown"]').click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
​
```

### [See demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/cVFyt/)

If the `images` divs don't necessarily directly follow the `dropdown` divs, you can use some regex to accomplish the task:

```
$('div[id$="dropdown"]').click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $toggleDiv = $('#' + this.id.replace(/^(.*?)dropdown$/, '$1images'));
    $toggleDiv.slideToggle();
});
​
```

### [See demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/cVFyt/1/)

Comment: That doesn't work for some reason. Have renamed my 'button' div with an image in to "nameAdropdown" and then the collapsable div to "nameAimages"using the code you gave me and nothing happened when it is clicked?

Comment: Examine the working jsfiddle demos carefully and reconstruct your HTML and JS if necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Worked a treat. was missing a } on the closing of the $(window).load(function(){
Appreciate the help! Is there a thank you button to give you reputation or anything?

Comment: Just accepting the answer and up-voting.  Glad it worked out for you.  Cheers!